# Link not working in anchor tag in django Template

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a django project with custom user model. When the user registers, he also gives url of his company's website. I access and display it in the template using the **USER**. But it won't open as a separate link when I write it in an anchor tag as follows:

```
<li><b>Company Website</b><br><a href="{{ detail.company_site }}" target="_blank">{{ detail.company_site }}</a></li>
```

Instead it takes me to this link

```
http://localhost:8000/detail/ahftech.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself. I simply added https:// as follows:

**Before:**

```
<li><b>Company Website</b><br><a href="{{ detail.company_site }}" target="_blank">{{ detail.company_site }}</a></li
```

**After:**

```
<li><b>Company Website</b><br><a href="https://{{ detail.company_site }}" target="_blank">{{ detail.company_site }}</a></li>
```